# Promise Calls in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

New to React Native, and Javascript in general.  Currently, I am trying to enact a Promise to handle an undefined error while using the `react-native-sqlite-storage` package.

I was following this previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257908/return-data-to-component-from-db-helper-class-react-native), but have not succeeded in implementing the Promise properly from what I can tell.

Here my current function:

```
nextPackage (q_id: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        db.transaction(tx => { 
            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM Questions INNER JOIN Choices on Choices.q_id = Questions.global_id WHERE Questions.global_id = ?', [q_id], (tx, results) => {
                    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        console.log('item:', i);
                        console.log('row:', results.rows.item(i));
                        this.pack.push(results.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    resolve(this.pack);
                }, function (tx, error) {
                    reject(error);
            });
        })
    )
}
```

And the Screen that calls it:

```
this.pack = this.wrapper.nextPackage(this.session.data_next.qID)
        .then(data => { 
            console.log("Retrieved data: ", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })

    this.pkHelp = new PackageHelper(this.pack);
```

However, when I then try to access `this.pack[0]` I receive an `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.pack[0].choiceType')`.  console.log() has shown that the database rows are indeed being read in, and that choiceType is indeed the proper column name.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign the value to your pack like this. The returned value is in the `then` part. You can do something like this

```
this.wrapper.nextPackage(this.session.data_next.qID).then(data => {
   this.pkHelp = new PackageHelper(this.pack);
}).catch(error => {
   console.error(error);
});
```

Or you can use `await`. But you have to use it in the `async` function

```
try {
   this.pkHelp = await this.wrapper.nextPackage(this.session.data_next.qID);
   this.pkHelp = new PackageHelper(this.pack);
} catch(error) {
   console.error(error);
}
```